# Copy constructing a base class from an instance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, copy-constructor

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class ABCD(ABC):
    def __init__(self, abc, d):
        # How to initialize the base class with abc in here?
        self.d = d

abc = ABC(1, 2, 3)
abcd = ABCD(abc, 4)
print(abcd.a)
```

What is a Pythonic way of initializing the base class with `abc`? If I used

```
super().__init__(abc.a, abc.b, abc.c)
```

I would have to change `ABCD` everytime I add someting to `ABC`. What I could do is to use

```
self.__dict__.update(abc.__dict__)
```

However, this feels clumsy and will break when `ABC` uses a different underlying implementation than `dict` (e.g. `__slots__`). Are there some alternative ways?

Comment: If you put the arguments specific to `ABCD` at the beginning, you could do: `__init__ (self, d, *args, **kargs)` and then `super().__init__(*args, **kargs)`.

Comment: @Holt: Then I would need to use `abcd = ABCD(4, abc.a, abc.b, abc.c)` instead of `abcd = ABCD(4, abc)`, thus forcing the user of `ABCD` to unpack `abc` manually.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the end of your code, I though you wanted to do `ABCD(4, 1, 2, 3)` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an object of type abc to the constructor, maybe you should have abc as field and not inheritance.

e.g. maybe:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class ABCD:
    def __init__(self, abc, d):
        # How to initialize the base class with abc in here?
        self.abc = abc

abc = ABC(1, 2, 3)
abcd = ABCD(abc, 4)
print(abcd.abc.a)
```

Per your comment, I would write method to copy the ABC part. This way this method would be "responsibility" of ABC.

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def copy_init(other):
        self.a = other.a
        self.b = other.b
        self.c = other.c

class ABCD(ABC):
    def __init__(self, abc, d):
        self.copy_init(abc)
        self.d = d
```

Comment: Yes, this is often the case. However, in my particular case, I need `ABCD` to inherit from `ABC` so it behaves like a subclass of `ABC` and the users can access all of `ABC`'s attributes directly.

Comment: In that case, I would write a method (of ABC) to do this copying. See EDIT above

Comment: @eran Copying ABC is not very practical if you are inheriting a giant class from an external library. It's hard to ensure all things get copies in the correct way.